# Inserting value in orderedict by index?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, ordereddictionary

Let say I have this ordered dictionary:

```
import collections

d = collections.OrderedDict([('a', None), ('b', None), ('c', None)])
```

And I have these values in a list:

```
lst = [10, 5, 50]
```

Now when I iterate over list, I would like to insert it's value in dictionary `d` by that list index. So basically the order I need is correct, I just don't know how to insert (if its possible) in dictionary by index, not by specifying key.

So for example (with pseudo code here):

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    d.index(i) = lst[i] #this is pseudo code, so there might not be such methods etc.
```

Comment: To update value at arbitrary position, `d[d.keys()[i]]=...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over both dictionary keys and values from list and assign the values:

```
>>> d = collections.OrderedDict([('a', None), ('b', None), ('c', None)])
>>> lst = [10, 5, 50]
>>> for k, val in zip(d, lst):
        d[k] = val
...     
>>> d
OrderedDict([('a', 10), ('b', 5), ('c', 50)])
```

And if you already know the keys then instead of initializing of dict first and then assigning values to it can be replaced with:

```
>>> keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> lst = [10, 5, 50]
>>> collections.OrderedDict(zip(keys, lst))
OrderedDict([('a', 10), ('b', 5), ('c', 50)])
```